# Combine two images with openCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, data-processing

I have the original image in RGB. After some transformations I got the second image. I was wondering if I could combine both images in such a way that I got a third one mixing black background and the butterfly, something like AND operator.

[image]
[image]

Please, ignore the headings.

Comment: OpenCV supports [bitwise operations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) like the `AND` operation. However, the output might be different from what you expect. All the pixels that are not `AND`ed with a value of `255` will be entirely black. Also consider that your input image is `BGR` (3 channels) and the binary mask probably contains just one channel.

Comment: I don't know what result you really expect but if you want to remove background then you have too much black pixel in second image. It would need only black pixel in background and white pixel in place on butterfly - and then you can use it as `mask` in `OpenCV` to remove pixels.

Comment: maybe better ask on [OpenCV forum](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: @stateMachine I've already tried AND operation but with no success.

Comment: @furas well, what you are saying is basically detecting the butterfly and that is exactly what I want to achieve with this.